# How to highlight selected row of a data grid that is inside another datagrid

Tags: wpf

WPF Desktop application.

I am using a datagrid and I have a datagrid inside that using the RowDetailsTemplate tag.

Whilst all the data is displayed OK I cannot seem to select an highlight a row in the child datagrid?

Comment: Why dont you post some code?

Comment: Hi I could do after o finished at the gym :) the only reason o had not was that it seems a limitation of wpf rather than my code.

Comment: I could be wrong and will post code when I can

Comment: Haven't tried datagrid in datagrid yet. But still eager to know why it happens. The selection should be possible. But why did you use a grid in grid? May I know?

Comment: @IDisposable Hi,  Well, I got child objects to my main objects and wanted to show that in  a grid